# How to pass NSTimeInterval value from swift to objective C through segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I got a value in Swift:

```
var diff:NSTimeInterval!
```

And I am passing it to Objective C class:

```
var destVC:ProgressViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ProgressViewController //as! UIViewController
destVC.seconds = self.diff!
```

Below the variable which accepts the value is in Objective C:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSTimeInterval *seconds;
```

But I get an error in Swift:

```
Cannot assign a value of type 'NSTimeInterval' to a value of type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<NSTimeInterval>'
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `NSTimeInterval seconds` and no `NSTimeInterval *seconds;`, remove the `*`.

Comment: Thank you for saving me hours!

Answer (score 0):

NSTimeInterval is actually a typedef to double value. It's not an object so you do not need to add a pointer for his property.

```
@property (nonatomic) NSTimeInterval seconds;
```